# can not upgrade xorg after update to ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, xorg, 17.04

I did an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 which seem to be all ok. Beside one issue:
When i run sudo apt-upgrade I get the message that the xorg package is hodl back.
`Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:  xorg`
I tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but this did not help.

With apt list I get some more info:

```
 apt list --upgradable -a
xorg/zesty 1:7.7+16ubuntu3 amd64 [aktualisierbar von: 1:7.7+13ubuntu3]
xorg/now 1:7.7+13ubuntu3 amd64  [Installiert,aktualisierbar auf:     1:7.7+16ubuntu3]
```

Does any one know how to:

- find out why the package is hold back
- do the upgrade ?

Thanks a lot 
Michael

Comment: try `apt` instead of `apt-get`

Comment: This does not make a difference

Comment: https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue after `do-release-upgrade` from 16.04 to 17.04:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all
```

fixed it. It asked me to remove some 16.04 components of `ubuntu-mate-desktop`, I confirmed with 'y' and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Since I knew it is xorg I tried:
`sudo apt-get install xorg -f`

I got the result that xorg depends on xserver-xorg and that there are not fulfilled dependencies. So I reinstalled the xserver plus dependencies:
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg -f --reinstall`

After this I could reinstall xorg successfully: `sudo apt-get install xorg -f --reinstall`